# Get data from firebase when within distance

Tags: javascript, get, firebase, snapshot

I want to : GET data (=previous chat messages) from Firebase when entering 300m of a chatroom geolocation.

My Code :

Here is my basic Firebase chat function :

```
var myDataRef = new Firebase("https://digitaldatastrategi.firebaseio.com/");
  $('#messageInput').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      var name = $('#nameInput').val();
      var text = $('#messageInput').val();
      myDataRef.push({name: name, text: text});
      $('#messageInput').val('');
  }
```

});

```
myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
var message = snapshot.val();
displayChatMessage(message.name, message.text);
```

});

```
function displayChatMessage(name, text) {
    $('<div/>').text(text).prepend($('<em/>').text(name+': ')).appendTo($('#messagesDiv'));
    $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
  };
```

Here is my "activate Chatroom when within 300m" function :

if (chatroom) {

```
jQuery("#chat").slideDown("slow");
myDataRef    = new Firebase(firebaseURL + chatroom[0]);

console.log("You are in:", chatroom);
```

}

else {

```
jQuery("#chat").slideUp("slow");
console.log("You are not in a chatroom");
```

} 
}

How can I do so not only does a chatroom active when I get within 300m but I ALSO get the data from firebase that is located at that chatroom. 
I can't manage to make the function(snapshot) to work properly. Only "undefined" appears in the chatroom window.

much appreciated.
/a.

Comment: Hmm. Where is your within 300m logic? I'm not seeing that anywhere. As for debugging the `undefined`, have you checked out the forge view of your data (i.e. visit https://digitaldatastrategi.firebaseio.com/ -- maybe the data you are saving to Firebase is undefined?), and are you familiar with the javascript console? Try [setting a breakpoint](https://digitaldatastrategi.firebaseio.com/) in your Firebase callback.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at GeoFire, a library built on top of Firebase that  lets you perform GeoQueries such as these: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-09-25-location-queries-geofire.html