# What's the best way to limit the messages in an AngularJS Chatroom

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, firebase, pubnub

Ok, so here's the setup:

Building a Realtime AngularJS chat application. However, I want to limit the messages the user sees by an API call that determines other messages within their proximity.

For some reason, I can't wrap my head around this. I've explored socket.io, FireBase, PubNub, and I can't seem to come up with a good way to limit the data that comes back from these services based on an API call that sets parameters.

Thoughts?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578303/get-data-from-firebase-when-within-distance and http://amscotti.github.io/firebasemapexample/#/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Geohashing Chat by Proximity

#### Try it now: [Geohash Chat by Proximity](http://stephenlb.github.io/geohash-chat-by-proximity/)

To connect groups of two or more people by location, you will take lat/long values and reduce the resolution of accuracy, and by doing this you can expand the coverage of proximity.  You can use multiple resolutions at once or a fixed resolution.

> Get Source Code: [GitHub Repository for Geo Chat by Proximity](https://github.com/stephenlb/geohash-chat-by-proximity)

[image: Geohashing Chat Conversations based on Proximity Zoom Level]

### Basics of Geo Hashing

Next we'll cover some source code snippet for geo hashing lat/long coords. It is fairly simple to increase the radius of lat/long position by reducing the accuracy of the float values.  Using this you can expand the circle and collect a Lat/Long.

```
// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
// Geo Hash
// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
function geohash( coord, resolution ) {
    var rez = Math.pow( 10, resolution || 0 );
    return Math.floor(coord * rez) / rez;
}
```

[image: Acquire Lat Long Chat Proximity Location]

### Geo Hashing Resolution "Zoom"

"Zoom" levels, basically several different cartesian grids with larger and smaller granularity.  Once a Geofencing event fires, you will publish to a set of channels corresponding with each zoom level.  Zoom levels are important as that is how we actually construct the link between Geofencing and PubNub.  Zoom level is the resolution/de-resolution of the Cartesian coordinates Lat/Long (think X,Y coord).  By reducing the resolution of the lat/long coord we can construct a channel name that hits 1 box of the grid.  Less resolution means larger the boxes and is required to determine a PubNub Channel that is associated.

```
// Create Proximity Channel
channel = geohash( pos.latitude, 0 ) + '' + geohash( pos.longitude, 0 );
```

This will create a very wide circle and generate a channel name used to connect.  Next connect to PubNub with this channel name.

```
// Connect to Proximity Channel
pubnub.subscribe({
     channel : channel,
     message : receive,
     connect : ready,
    presence : presence
});
```

[image: Acquired Latitude Longitude Chat Proximity Group]

### Multiplexing 9 Boxes

You will calculate the surrounding squares to extend the taper and radius in a way that provides more accuracy.  This will remove the "fencing" effect.

### Geo Hashing with PubNub Conclusion

That's it! You simply reduce the resolution of a geo coordinate and use that as a channel name on PubNub.  Also check out the browser's `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(...)` method to acquire lat/long in a chrome/firefox/ie/opera/mobile/safari browser.

> Also checkout the [PubNub Connected Car Solution Kit](http://www.pubnub.com/developers/connected-car/)

[image: Geohashing Chat Conversations based on Proximity Nearby]

Comment: This is a clever solution and works well, however it treats the box as the fence, not the user. So, the user would only be connected to people within their box, not treating the user as the radius for the messages they see.

So, for example, if a user A is on the very left edge of Box 1, and user B is on the very right edge of the adjacent Box 2, even though they are right next to each other, they wouldn't be in the same chat room.

Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: "Next-to" is relative. Zoom in another level and "next-to" become "!next-to". Perhaps you could break the current user's level/box into the next level of 9 sub boxes. 
1) If the user is in the center box, just work with the current box.
2) If the user is within the "right center" sub box, then include the right adjacent full box.
3) If the user is in the "top right" sub box, then include the adjacent full boxes above, to the right and diagonally up and right.
Will that help?

Comment: You can use PubNub Multiplexing and connect to all surrounding 8 boxes.

Comment: Multiplexing 9 Boxes -- You will calculate the surrounding squares to extend the taper and radius in a way that provides more accuracy. This will remove the "fencing" effect.